# How to echo Current date of AD Solar(هجری خورشیدی) with php on my view codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to echo the AD Solar or hijri khorshidi with php on the view part,

i am useing codeigniter framwork.

thanks

Comment: what you want actually? If you want to echo today's date echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

Comment: no not to days date please read my question.i have add AD Solar.see on dictionary, plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript Conversion might be helpful for you (converting AD to hijri khorshidi)

```
<script>

    function gmod(n,m){
    return ((n%m)+m)%m;
}

function kuwaiticalendar(adjust){
    var today = new Date();
    if(adjust) {
        adjustmili = 1000*60*60*24*adjust; 
        todaymili = today.getTime()+adjustmili;
        today = new Date(todaymili);
    }
    day = today.getDate();
    month = today.getMonth();
    year = today.getFullYear();
    m = month+1;
    y = year;
    if(m<3) {
        y -= 1;
        m += 12;
    }

    a = Math.floor(y/100.);
    b = 2-a+Math.floor(a/4.);
    if(y<1583) b = 0;
    if(y==1582) {
        if(m>10)  b = -10;
        if(m==10) {
            b = 0;
            if(day>4) b = -10;
        }
    }

    jd = Math.floor(365.25*(y+4716))+Math.floor(30.6001*(m+1))+day+b-1524;

    b = 0;
    if(jd>2299160){
        a = Math.floor((jd-1867216.25)/36524.25);
        b = 1+a-Math.floor(a/4.);
    }
    bb = jd+b+1524;
    cc = Math.floor((bb-122.1)/365.25);
    dd = Math.floor(365.25*cc);
    ee = Math.floor((bb-dd)/30.6001);
    day =(bb-dd)-Math.floor(30.6001*ee);
    month = ee-1;
    if(ee>13) {
        cc += 1;
        month = ee-13;
    }
    year = cc-4716;

    if(adjust) {
        wd = gmod(jd+1-adjust,7)+1;
    } else {
        wd = gmod(jd+1,7)+1;
    }

    iyear = 10631./30.;
    epochastro = 1948084;
    epochcivil = 1948085;

    shift1 = 8.01/60.;

    z = jd-epochastro;
    cyc = Math.floor(z/10631.);
    z = z-10631*cyc;
    j = Math.floor((z-shift1)/iyear);
    iy = 30*cyc+j;
    z = z-Math.floor(j*iyear+shift1);
    im = Math.floor((z+28.5001)/29.5);
    if(im==13) im = 12;
    id = z-Math.floor(29.5001*im-29);

    var myRes = new Array(8);

    myRes[0] = day; //calculated day (CE)
    myRes[1] = month-1; //calculated month (CE)
    myRes[2] = year; //calculated year (CE)
    myRes[3] = jd-1; //julian day number
    myRes[4] = wd-1; //weekday number
    myRes[5] = id; //islamic date
    myRes[6] = im-1; //islamic month
    myRes[7] = iy; //islamic year

    return myRes;
}
function writeIslamicDate(adjustment) {
    var wdNames = new Array("Ahad","Ithnin","Thulatha","Arbaa","Khams","Jumuah","Sabt");
    var iMonthNames = new Array("Muharram","Safar","Rabi'ul Awwal","Rabi'ul Akhir",
    "Jumadal Ula","Jumadal Akhira","Rajab","Sha'ban",
    "Ramadan","Shawwal","Dhul Qa'ada","Dhul Hijja");
    var iDate = kuwaiticalendar(adjustment);
    var outputIslamicDate = wdNames[iDate[4]] + ", " 
    + iDate[5] + " " + iMonthNames[iDate[6]] + " " + iDate[7] + " AH";
    return outputIslamicDate;
}

document.write("<h3>without date adjustment</h3>");
    document.write(writeIslamicDate()); //without date adjustment

    document.write("<h3>with 1 day date adjustment</h3>");

    document.write(writeIslamicDate(1)); //with 1 day date adjustment

    </script>
```

Live Demo Here>> [Codefiddle](http://codepad.viper-7.com/FmnoNK)

JavaScript File Here>> [hijricalendar-kuwaiti.js](http://www.al-habib.info/islamic-calendar/hijricalendar-kuwaiti.js)